# Why are my prototype cells are not showing up when I run my app on the simulator/a device.(Parallax Header For UITableView)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, parallax

I was following the tutorial below in order to create a parallax header for my UITableView. I was able to successfully get it working, but now my prototype cells are not showing up on my project(inside of the UITableView) when I run it on the simulator and on my physical device. I've been trying to figure out why this is the case for the past few hours, but I am stumped. I would greatly appreciate it if anybody could help me out. (Sorry if the answer is obvious, I'm pretty new to Swift.)

This is the link to the tutorial/code I was using: 
http://runmad.com/blog/2015/08/parallax-uitableview-header-with-auto-layout/

Comment: Add your UI images.

Comment: share your code as the url link you shared  works fine and doesn't reflect your issue.

Comment: I ended up using,  `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CommentsTableViewCell` and that seemed to work. Not entirely sure why or how that works though.